# Export Only Slides Within a Certain Section in Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have code that exports slides to PNG files if they meet certain criteria (i.e. have a certain named shape in the slide). There will be occassions where slides will not have any known shape names, but they will be within a named "section".

I know I must somehow use the ActivePresentation.SectionProperties, but I am not sure how to go about doing this. I've tried things along the line of the below code with no success. In this example the name of the section is "Test". There will be many different sections and I would need to do this for several of those sections. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

```
Dim sld As Slide
i = 1

For Each sld in ActivePresentation.Slides

If ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Name("Test") Then
   ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Export filenamepng & "TEST" & i & ".png", "PNG"
End If

i = i + 1

Next
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Hunter21188

I guess this is what you need.

You will check of which section every slide belongs.
After this you verify if it's from "Test" section, if is true gotcha! Export.

Obs. The function convert SectionIndex, from Slide Atribute to SectionName, that is not in Slides collection.

```
Sub Test_Export()

Dim sld As Slide
i = 1

DesiredSection = SectionIndexOf("Test")

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides

If sld.sectionIndex = DesiredSection Then
   ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Export filenamepng & "TEST" & i & ".png", "PNG"
End If

i = i + 1

Next


End Sub

Function SectionIndexOf(sSectionName As String) As Long
    Dim x As Long
    With ActivePresentation.SectionProperties
        For x = 1 To .Count
            If .Name(x) = sSectionName Then
                SectionIndexOf = x
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Good answer (take your upvote!). A couple quick observations: you don't need the variable `i` - just use `sld.SlideNumber` so you don't have to increment anything (I know you were following OP's code format, it's just an observation); also I recommend to always use `Option Explicit` to declare all your variables to keep track of what you're doing.

Comment: @PeterT Thanks for the comment. I'll keep that in mind. The reason I had the variable `i` was because I wanted it to attach a number to the end of the filename based on the number of slides within that section. The way I did it does not work and it does indeed just use the slide number. Still working on figuring that one out so the first slide within the section has a 1 at the end of the name, the second a 2, etc - regardless of what the slide number is.

Comment: @PeterT Unless there's a valid reason to use sld.SlideNumber, it's better to use sld.SlideIndex.  SlideIndex returns the ordinal rank of the slide within the presentation (ie, the 42nd slide will always be SlideIndex=42 as well). SlideNumber is less predictable, as the user can set the starting number, so if the user's set the starting number to be 42, then the second slide would return SlideNumber = 43.  SlideNumber is useful when you need to know the number that will appear when slide numbering (ie, in footers) is active.